# Installing Isotope + packery-mode with Bower

Tags: bower, jquery-isotope, packery

I'm trying to install packery-mode with bower. I have this `bower.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
  "isotope": "^3.0.4",
  "isotope-packery": "^2.0.0"
},
"overrides": {
    "isotope": {
      "main": [
        "./dist/isotope.pkgd.js"
      ],
      "dependencies": {}
    },
    "isotope-packery": {
      "main": [
        ".packery-mode.pkgd.js"
      ],
      "dependencies": {}
    },
  }
}
```

And the isotope init:

```
var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
      layoutMode: 'packery',
      itemSelector: '.post'
    });
```

I get an `Uncaught Error: No layout mode: packery` in the console. Why? packery-mode is present in the main.js (masonry layout works fine).

Answer (score 0):

There was just a typo: missing slash in overrides.

```
".packery-mode.pkgd.js"
```

instead

```
"./packery-mode.pkgd.js"
```

Sorry for the noise